# swiftyjson - Call can throw, but it is marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

Tags: swift, swifty-json

I am trying to use swiftyjson and I am getting an Error:

> Call can throw, but it is marked with 'try' and the error is not
>   handled.

I have validated that my source JSON is good. I've been searching and cannot find a solution to this problem

```
import Foundation


class lenderDetails
{

func loadLender()
{

    let lenders = ""

    let url = URL(string: lenders)!
    let session =  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url)
    {
        (data, response, error) in


        guard let data = data else
        {
            print ("data was nil?")
            return
        }

        let json = JSON(data: data)
        print(json)
    }

    session.resume()
}
}
```

Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should wrap it into a `do-catch` block. In your case:

```
do {
    let session =  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
        (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else {
            print ("data was nil?")
            return
        }

        let json = JSON(data: data)
        print(json)
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    // error
}
```

Answer (score 59):

The SwiftyJSON initializer `throws`, the declaration is

```
public init(data: Data, options opt: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions = []) throws
```

You have three options:

1. Use a `do - catch` block and handle the error (the recommended one).

   ```
   do {
      let json = try JSON(data: data)
      print(json)
   } catch {
      print(error)
      // or display a dialog
   }
   ```
2. Ignore the error and optional bind the result (useful if the error does not matter).

   ```
   if let json = try? JSON(data: data) {
      print(json)
   }
   ```
3. Force unwrap the result

   ```
   let json = try! JSON(data: data)
   print(json)
   ```

   Use this option only if it's guaranteed that the attempt will never fail (not in this case!). `Try!` can be used for example in `FileManager` if a directory is one of the default directories the framework creates anyway.

For more information please read [Swift Language Guide - Error Handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH42-ID508)

Comment: This sould be the selected answer!

Comment: Thanks no 3 work for me.. don't know why but no 1 and 2 didnt work =-=" any idea why? *just curious why

Comment: @dmh All three ways are supposed to work. What error message do you get?

Comment: "Call can throw, but it is marked with 'try' and the error is not handled". got eror... even after trying to rebuild the project and closing the xcode workspace,,

Comment: @dmh Check the balance of the braces of the `do - catch` block

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to implement `do{} catch{}` block. Inside `do` block you have to call throwable function with try.